# Defining a variable inside the try block of the useQuery function (tanstack's react-query)

Tags: javascript, try-catch, react-query

I encountered a weird issue where I couldn't define a variable inside an anonymous function which had a try catch block defined in it.

```
  let response: AxiosResponse<CustomType[]>;  // had to define outside the useQuery
  const { data: info } = useQuery(
    ['queryKey', a, b],
    async () => {
     // let response: AxiosResponse<CustomType[]>; //ERROR variable response is used before being assigned
      try {
        response = await getAxios().get(`requestURL`);
        const responseFiltered = {};
        response.data.forEach((a) => {
           responseFiltered[a] = a;
         })
        return responseFiltered;
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error({
          meta: { error, response}, // variable used here
        });
      }
    }
  );
```

Not sure why it expects the response variable to be defined outside the useQuery function.

Comment: what kind of error are you getting? is this from eslint, or from typescript, or at runtime? Also, you are using `responseFiltered` in the catch block where it doesn't exist.

Comment: @TkDodo Thanks for pointing that out. I did mean to type that as response in the catch block which I have updated now. It's a typescript error `variable response is used before being assigned`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling the compiler that response will be of type `AxiosReponse`. However, you are not giving response a "value" in branches. `response` is assigned inside the try/catch, so in the `catch` clause, it might still be `undefined`. That's what TypeScript is trying to tell you.

To fix this, define your response as being potentially undefined:

```
let response: AxiosResponse<CustomType[]> | undefined
```

Then you can use it in the `catch` block. Even though, very likely, in the catch block it *will* be undefined if the network request fails.

With axios, the `error` is actually an `AxiosError`, which will contain the response, so maybe you'd want something like this?

```
const { data: info } = useQuery(
    ['queryKey', a, b],
    async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`requestURL`);
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
                console.error({
                    meta: { error, response: error.response },
                });
            }
            throw error
        }
    }
);
```

Please further keep in mind that catching an error just to log it is not ideal with `react-query`, because it "swallows" the error. You can see that I've re-thrown the error at the end of the catch block. A better approach would be to use the `onError` callback:

```
const { data: info } = useQuery(
    ['queryKey', a, b],
    async () => {
        return await axios.get(`requestURL`);
    }, {
    onError: (error) => {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            console.error({
                meta: { error, response: error.response },
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tkdodo! for the detailed explanation and suggesting the `onError` callback approach. Much appreciated!